# DLL exporting causing issues with unique pointers

Tags: c++, stl, c++14, c++17, dllexport

I've got two files:

**Header.h**

```
#pragma once

#ifdef UNIQUEPTRISSUE_EXPORTS
#define UNIQUEPTRISSUE_API __declspec(dllexport)   
#else  
#define UNIQUEPTRISSUE_API __declspec(dllimport)   
#endif
```

**UniquePtrIssue.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "Header.h"

#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class UNIQUEPTRISSUE_API ClassA {

};

class UNIQUEPTRISSUE_API ClassB {
private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ClassA>> x;
};
```

Compiling raises the following error:

> 1>d:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual
>   studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\xutility(2443):
>   error C2280: 'std::unique_ptr>
>   &std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::operator =(const
>   std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)': attempting to
>   reference a deleted function
>       1>        with
>       1>        [
>       1>            _Ty=ClassA
>       1>        ]

Similar issues seem to arise when the accessing the copy constructor of a `unique_ptr` but they don't seem to apply.

Removing the `UNIQUEPTRISSUE_API`/`__declspec(dllexport)` from both class declarations seems to make the error go away.

Obviously something is going on with the `__declspec(dllexport)` declaration that I don't understand. Is there any way I can use `unique_ptr`s between exported classes?

Comment: Why are you exporting classes from a DLL to begin with? That is highly compiler-dependent.  Even if you could export without error, you wouldn't be able to use your class in other compilers, especially if it depends on STL classes, since the DLL user may not be using the same STL implementation as your DLL.  You should strive to stay away from using non-POD data over DLL boundaries.

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau 
I'm not too bothered about compiler dependency since this is a personal project that I only expect myself to use. The reason I'm exporting classes in the first place is because I intend for clients to be able to subclass them. Are there other ways of providing polymorphism and inheritance over a DLL boundary?

Comment: Even if you use it for yourself, someday you might need to update your compiler, and that would require recompiling the DLL to match. Polymorphism doesn't really work very well over DLL boundaries, and inheritance is best limited to the DLL exposing access to only abstract interfaces (like what COM does).

Comment: Weirdly enough, I cannot reproduce the bug on http://rextester.com...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you declare a class with `declspec(dllexport)`, the compiler must generate all of the member functions of the class, including the default constructors, copy assignment, etc functions since it doesn't know which ones may be needed by the importing module.  This is described in [Using dllimport and dllexport in C++ classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/81h27t8c.aspx).

Since a `unique_ptr` cannot be copied, its copy constructor and copy assignment operators are deleted, and when the vector object tries to use them you get the `C2280` error.

When you don't include `declspec(dllexport)`, the compiler will only generate the functions that are actually used, and the problematic copies are avoided.

One way around this problem is to export the individual class member functions, which may mean specifying some of them as defaulted.  `virtual` functions would not need to be exported, since they're handled by the vtable.

Another workaround is to explicitly delete the copy constructor and copy assignment operator.  Since this will prevent the creation of a default constructor and move constructor/assignment functions, you may need to default those in.

```
class UNIQUEPTRISSUE_API ClassB {
public:
    ClassB(const ClassB &) = delete;
    ClassB &operator=(const ClassB &) = delete;
    // You may need to explicitly default these if they are used
    ClassB() = default;
    ClassB &operator=(ClassB &&) = default;
    ClassB(ClassB &&) = default;
private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ClassA>> x;
};
```

Comment: It's concise, but it's inaccurate: `std::vector` works just fine with movable-only types. I would consider MSVC's behaviour a bug there. `ClassB` is itself movable-only, so there is no reason why a copy-assignment operator should be generated and cause an error.

Comment: @Quentin Interesting. This is why I was originally confused as I know it's very possible to have vectors of unique_ptrs despite unique_ptrs only being movable.

Comment: I tried you code in vs 2017 and it works. Which compiler version you use?

Comment: @Quentin It accurately describes the compiler's behavior, which is a compiler extension to the language.  This behavior apparently has not been updated to account for move-only classes being exported.  The compiler will give an error when trying to use the deleted function when declaring the class as `dllimport`, so there is no reason I'm aware of that the export behavior can't be modified.

Comment: Fair enough. I just expected more emphasis on the fact that it is a compiler issue, since `std::vector` has no business trying to copy its non-copyable contents.

Comment: @Alistair401 I've updated my answer with a couple of possible workarounds

Answer (score 1):

You can expose class differently:

```
class ClassB {
private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ClassA>> x;

public:

    UNIQUEPTRISSUE_API ClassB(ClassB&&) {

    }

    UNIQUEPTRISSUE_API ClassB& operator==(ClassB&&) {

        return* this;

    }

private:

}
```

i.e: don't export the entire class, but the single function.
I try this on vs2010 and vs2017